# Algorithm for Leaderboard Performance

Tags: algorithms

Here's the situation

I'm working on a leaderboard algorithm where multiple parameters play role.

```
Correct Answer - c  ~ Higher you score, better your Rating
Max Answers    - m
Time Taken     - t  ~ Faster you play better you Rating
```

I am currently working with the following algorithm where p is Performance

```
X = 10000000
Y = 1000000

p = ( (c / m) * X ) + ( (1 / t) * Y )
```

There are some issues with this algorithm due to following cases

**Case 1**

```
c == m

Player A has scores [c=5/m=5/t=10000]
Player B has scores [c=8/m=8/t=10000]
```

The above scenario produces same performance but ideally longer quiz that requires more efforts should be better rewarded.

I'm unable to come up with a decent algorithm with weighted parameters.

Appreciate suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It all gets down to what behaviors you want to reward.

It sounds like you want to reward based on raw number of questions answered (so longer quizzes count more).

So what about something like this?

$$P = cX' + Y'/t_{avg}$$.

Here, $c$ is the total number of correct answers, and $t_{avg}$ is the average time spent per question.